# Destroy gameObject in random range

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

Look i dont have error but its not work to me

you know why??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tTz7.png)

Comment: you want a random number instead of maxscale?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `(int)Mathf.Round(Random.Range(1, 5))` which you could then check if it was equal to any number. Any number will have about a 1 in 5 chance.

You could use this script to detect clicks:

```
public float randomness = 2f;
void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
   {
        if ((int)Mathf.Round(Random.Range(0f, randomness)) == 0)
        {
            //Destroy the object

            //This will have a 1/2 chance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is not work my problem is that i cant destroy my object in a random scale              my scripts work but he destroy the object in the scale that i decides and i want that this is be random like one time its take me two click and the next time five or six like random ok? you can help me??

Comment: @RoMMk I will edit my answer right now. **Make sure to check it** it will be edited.

Comment: the scripts dont work

Comment: (Random.Range(0f, randomness) == 0) this is give me a error

Comment: @RoMMk Ok I changed it. I edited original answer. Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: this dont solve it i edit my first comment and add to her a picture of my problem

Comment: @RoMMk I am nearly positive I figured it out. You must remove the `OnMouseDown()` function. Just put your scaleFactor and maxScale code directly in the if(...Mathf.Round...) statement. **2. Important: Change BOTH 0s in the random statment to 1s** This way it is a 1 in 2 chance and not a 1 in 3

Comment: i don't have error but its not Destroy i just can't click on the sphere after two time but its not Destroy u update the picture in the first comment Look at the picture and plssssss help me figure its out

Comment: @RoMMk I did put your exact script in a unity project, and it worked. I clicked about 6 times, it sometimes grew bigger, then it got destroyed. **Can you also send a picture of the inspector and scene view? (of the gameObject this script is attached to)** thanks

Comment: its get destroy in the maxscale but its not random

Comment: Oh ok. Is `randomness` set to 2 or higher? in the inspector? also, a screenshot of your unity project **including inspetor** would be very helpful

Comment: i put the screen shot in the first comment

Comment: By not random do you mean that every click makes it bigger? **IF so, increase randomness by a lot to like 10.**

Comment: now when i click four to five times and i try the six it not destroy it just don't click

Comment: @RoMMk put a variable that stores the random value that is created in the if statement. then compare that value if it is == to 0. Outside of the if statement print the value you get, and in the if statement print if it was true. **so, just two print statements printing if the if statement went through, and what the value was.**